# How to make a search query in stored procedure with OR, AND keyword using php and mysql?

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am making a search query in stored procedure but the problem is that everytime I search for a word it displays an error.

my stored procedure

```
DELIMITER//
CREATE PROCEDURE viewMedicine(product_name varchar(40), description text)
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
begin
    PREPARE STMT FROM "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name like ? OR description like ? ORDER BY ASC";
        SET @s=product_name;
        SET @ss=description;
    EXECUTE STMT USING @s, @ss;
end//
DELIMITER;
```

php code:

```
                $search="";

                if(isset($_POST['search_txt'])){    

                    $search=$_POST['search_txt'];

                    if($search!="")

                        $sql="Call searchMedicine('$search%')";

                    else
                        $sql="SELECT id, product_name, description, price, quantity, date FROM products ORDER BY product_name ASC";
                }
                else
                    $sql="SELECT id, product_name, description, price, quantity, date FROM products ORDER BY product_name ASC";

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                while($test = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {

                    $id = $test['id'];
            ?>
```

Comment: Did your cat jump on your keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error are you seeing?  Your sproc is called viewMedicine and has two arguments, product_name and description.  Your sql code is calling searchMedicine and is only passing one parameter, $search.

Your call of mysql_fetch_array is most likely incorrect.  You need to pass the mysql_result object that is returned by mysqli_query.  I can't tell for sure without seeing more of your code.  Please see my comment.

EDIT: Thanks for providing the code.  Your use of mysqli_query is correct but there is a syntax or argument error.  Looking at the definition of your SPROC, I'd say it's an argument error.

Try making the following changes:

```
$search="";

if (isset($_POST['search_txt'])){    

    $search=$_POST['search_txt'];

    if($search!="")
        $sql="Call viewMedicine('$search%', '')";
    else
        $sql="SELECT id, product_name, description, price, quantity, date FROM products ORDER BY product_name ASC";
 }
 else {
     $sql="SELECT id, product_name, description, price, quantity, date FROM products ORDER BY product_name ASC";
 }

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 if(!$result) {
     echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
 }
 else {
     while($test = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
         $id = $test['id'];
?>
```

If you do not need to search for description in your query, remove it from the SPROC:

```
PREPARE STMT FROM "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name like ?";
    SET @s=product_name;
EXECUTE STMT USING @s;
```

Then, your call in your code would become:

```
...

  if($search!="")
            $sql="Call viewMedicine('$search%')";
        else

...
```

EDIT 2:

If you want to search for the description, you will need to get it to the script.  You probably want to do it the same way you are doing the search for the product name, I assume, which is through the $_POST array, so I will write code for the assumption.  Be aware, of course, that you'll need to make the necessary changes to the webform which sends POST data to this script.

```
$search="";

if (isset($_POST['search_txt']) && 
    isset($_POST['description_txt'])){    

    $search=$_POST['search_txt'];
    $description=$_POST['description_txt'];

    if($search != "" && $description != "")
        $sql="Call viewMedicine('$search%', '%$description%')";
    else
        $sql="SELECT id, product_name, description, price, quantity, date FROM products ORDER BY product_name ASC";
 }
 else {
     $sql="SELECT id, product_name, description, price, quantity, date FROM products ORDER BY product_name ASC";
 }

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 if(!$result) {
     echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
 }
 else {
     while($test = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
         $id = $test['id'];
?>
```

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in`

Comment: Can you show the lines after $sql="Call searchMedicine('$search%')";  Especially the line that the stacktrace is showing that Warning on and the lines around it.

Comment: @user3808774 Please edit that specific error into your question so that the people who can help you are able to see it without reading through the comment section. Thanks!

Comment: @user3808774 Why aren't you checking for errors and printing `mysqli_error($conn)` to show the reason for the error?

Comment: Sir, I got this Error: Call searchMedicine('BIO%') Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE

Comment: @user3808774, Please see my updated answer with code sample.  Report back with the output for mysqli_error, please, if any exists.

Comment: How do I pass the one parameter into this stored proc query?  `PREPARE STMT FROM "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name like ? OR description like ? ORDER BY ASC";`

Comment: @user3808774, if you do not need to search for the $description in your query, remove it from the SPROC -- see my comment for the code to do this.

Comment: @user3808774, You made the changes I've outlined in my answer?  Please write back with what is output after running the code with my changes.  I want to see what is output by this line: echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));  What does it say after "Error description:" when you run the code with changes?

Comment: I need to search for the description of my query. What should I do?

Comment: @user3808774, The solution for this is in my answer.  Please take some time to read it and implement the changes within in.  If you find you are still having difficulties, comment here and I will try to help more -- but until you try to implement the solution I have already posted, I'm afraid I cannot do much more.  May I ask why you've chosen to use a SPROC for this query?  If you have a standard MySQL query that works, why not use that in place of the SPROC?

Comment: @user3808774 Again, please look at my answer and implement the changes in the block of code under "Try making the following changes:".  Leave your Stored Procedure as it was in your original question.  If failure, report back with the output of the script.  If success, yay!

Comment: please take a look at my query in this link: [My Stored Procedure Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/268m8qtrc4ahe2f/stored_proc.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: @user3808774.  Yes, that image you linked is not the same code as the code you have in your question.  Your original Stored Procedure code in your question is correct if you do, indeed, want to search by product_name or description.  Leave your SPROC code the same as it is in the original question and change the code as I've outlined in my answer (not in these comments, scroll up). http://pastebin.com/Qvz7Q1bF

Comment: Just to clarify I changed the viewMedicine to searchMedicine in the stored proc.

Comment: @user3808774, in that case, use searchMedicine in the calls to that SPROC.  I will not update my answer because it still matches your question.

Comment: Please take a look: [My Stored Procedure Image second try](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vm7x6w6rbtvzeeg/store_procproc.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: @user3808774 That looks fine -- looks like your original version in your question -- which was fine to begin with.  Your problems are in the PHP code, for which I've outlined changes in my answer.  Again, please implement these changes and report back.

Comment: It's works fine but I can't search for the description

Comment: I think it's working I modified the code: `$sql="Call searchMedicine('$search%', '$search%')";`